# Capybara Authentication session with devise

Tags: session, authentication, rspec, devise, capybara

I am attempting to put together a single run test in rspec:

```
feature "Happy Path", js:true do

  before(:all) do
    @user = create(:user)
    @object = create(:object, account: @object.account)
    sign_in @user
    visit root_path
  end

  describe "test" do
    context "test" do
      include_examples "it_will_expand_the_menu"

      include_examples "it_will_navigate_to_the_object" do
        let(:object) {@object.name}
      end
    end
  end
```

and the shared examples defined:

```
shared_examples "it_will_expand_the_menu" do
  it "expands menu" do
    ...
    ...
  end
end

shared_examples "it_will_navigate_to_the_object" do 
  it "fills in the country" do
    click_on object
  end
end
```

Furthermore, I've overwritten Capybara as follows:

```
module Capybara
  class << self
    def reset_sessions!
      nil
    end
    def use_default_driver
      nil
    end
  end


  class SpecHelper
    def reset!
      nil
    end
  end
  class Session
    def reset!
      return nil
    end
  end

  module Selenium
    class Driver
      def reset!
        nil
      end
    end
    module WebDriver
     class Driver
       def delete_all_cookies
         nil
       end
     end
    end
  end

  module Driver
    class Base
      def reset!
        nil
      end

      def cleanup!
        nil
      end

      def reset_session!
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  module RackTest
    class Driver
      def reset!
        nil
      end
    end
    class Browser
      def reset_host!
        nil
      end
      def reset_cache!
        nil
      end
    end
  end

end
```

However, I am logging out between actions that would navigate between pages. So after the navigate action, the test hits the initial log in screen of the application.

What is going on? Why is Capybara resetting my session? And how can I prevent it from doing so?